# Error thrown by AWS CLI to give permission to IoTAnalytics_Pipeline to invoke my Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-iot-analytics

I am trying to get permission for my IoT Analytics Pipeline to invoke my Lambda Function but I am unable to. It is giving me the error that **User is not authorized to perform lambda:AddPermission on Resource**. what is it? And how can I fix it? I am putting the command instruction in AWS CLI which is given in the User guide.
And 2nd is there any other way (especially through IAM) other than AWS CLI to get permission for my Pipeline to invoke my Lamdafunctions?

I used this instruction in AWS CLI:

aws lambda add-permission --function-name myLambda1 --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id iotanalytics --principal iotanalytics.amazonaws.com --source-account 123456789012 --source-arn arn:aws:iotanalytics:us-east-1:123456789012:pipeline/analytics_lambda1_pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the user admin on AWS that should resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes that actually worked. I was just assigning the User, the IoT Policy whereas AWS CLI requires that the User must have an Admin access to actually authorize any service to invoke Lambda. Thanks a lot